# Java Swing rotate & scale

Tags: java, swing

[Picture of the GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyjsO.jpg)

If I click the button, image rotate and size up down.
I want to make Replay Button that show the actions I clicked before.
For example, I clicked Scale up, Scale up, CCW, CW, CW buttons
and I click Replay button, shows all the action I clicked before. Scale up, Scale up, CCW, CW, CW.
I don't have idea how to make it

All the buttons are like this

```
class ScaleUpButtonListener implements ActionListener{
    private MyDrawPanel myDrawPanel;
    public ScaleUpButtonListener(MyDrawPanel mymy) {
        myDrawPanel = mymy;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        myDrawPanel.scaleJava(0.1);
    }
}
```

and the methods

```
public double angle = 0;
public double scale = 1.0;

public void rotateJava(double dangle) {
    angle += dangle;
    repaint();
}

public void scaleJava(double dsc) {
    scale += dsc;
    repaint();
}
```

the method I need:

```
public void replayJava() {
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: You will have to store all your actions in a List of some sort and then iterate over the List and output all elements when clicking the button. Did you try such an attempt and if so, why didn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an `Action` for each button. Part of the functionality for the `Action` would be to add itself to an `ArrayList`. Then for the "Replay" `Action` you would iterate through the `ArrayList` to invoke the Action directly.

```
class ScaleAction extends AbstractAction
{
    public ScaleAction()
    {
        putValue( Action.NAME, "Scale" );
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // code for scaling
 
        if (e != null)
            replayList.add( this );
    }
}
```

Then the code for you "Replay" Action would be something like:

```
class ReplayAction extends AbstractAction
{
    public ReplayAction()
    {
        putValue( Action.NAME, "Replay" );
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        for (Action action: replayList)
            action.actionPerformed( null );
    }
}
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more information.

Your actions would be defined as inner classes in your main class so they can all access the "replayList".

Comment: How can I change replayButton to show first action in order, go back to replayList[0] and show in order